# Configuring IIS 6.0 to execute cgi(.exe)

Tags: iis, iis-6, cgi

I already create a virtual directory (cgi-bin) with permission : Scripts and Executable...
When I test : http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe, I got 404 error, The page cannot be found

Am I supposed to Add a EXTENSION mapping to .exe files ? Which executable ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved that:

Go to Web Service Extensions in the IIS service manager 
Select Add a new web service extension. On the required files tab, add 
C:\YourMapserverInstalldir\mapserv.exe 
Set it to allow

Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to create an application mapping between the file name extension of your script and the script interpreter. Check out this link.

[Installing CGI Applications in IIS 6.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738130(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Thanks... What is the script interpreter to CGI?